# Create scene in blender

Tags: blender

How can one create a scene/terrain like clash royal's game scene in blender? The game scene seems like top view but is not exactly top view. At what angle should the camera be placed to get that effect?

Comment: Show some effort.Please provide something that you tried.

Answer (score 0):

You would be looking for [isometric projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_graphics_in_video_games_and_pixel_art) or maybe [2.5D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D), also called 3/4 perspective. You can find several [isometric tutorials on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender%20isometric).

While I'm not sure if there are any strict rules to follow unless you are making graphics that must fit in an existing game, it is common to use an orthographic camera at about a 45 degree angle.

Clash Royale looks like it could be close to a 45 degree orthographic camera angle.